# Retrieve all uploaded videos by a given user

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to get all videos that a user uploaded on YouTube (without the authentication token)? How?

Edit:
The best approach is this Pointy answer, but [there is a limit of 50 videos per request](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#max-resultssp), so in short there isn't a way to get all videos at once. Accepted anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search results in this page from the YouTube API docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#User_Uploaded_Videos

The responses from the API are XML documents. Each `<entry>` tag corresponds to an upload. The video "key" can be extracted from the `<id>` tag inside the entry; it's the tail end of the URL. (The URL in the `<id>` is *not* directly the URL for the video.

Comment: I don't want feeds, I want ALL videos.

Comment: When you get the feed, the URLs for each video can be extracted.